# Quisiera aplicar formato para numeros de telefono en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

*Necesito ayuda*

Así como en SQL puedes dar formato a números de teléfono, con un

```
N_Cel varchar(8) check((N_Cel)like '[2|7|8|5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') NOT NULL,
```

quiero hacer lo mismo en MySQL pero me marca error, ¿alguien podria explicarme?

*Gracias de antemano*

Comment: Te puede servir esta publicación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426487/how-to-format-a-numeric-column-as-phone-number-in-sql

Comment: Muchas gracias @ArmandoMariscal

Comment: @ArmandoMariscal crea una respuesta aquí, en español y referenciando esa otra publicación. De ese modo los usuarios que no sepan inglés podrán beneficiarse también de ella. Y así podría darte un +1 (uno de verdad, no uno en los comentarios)

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta con esto: (Funciona en S**QL Server**)

```
UPDATE TheTable
SET PhoneNumber = SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 1, 3) + '-' + 
                  SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 4, 3) + '-' + 
                  SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 7, 4)

CREATE FUNCTION FormatPhoneNumber(@phoneNumber VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(12)
BEGIN
    RETURN SUBSTRING(@phoneNumber, 1, 3) + '-' + 
           SUBSTRING(@phoneNumber, 4, 3) + '-' + 
           SUBSTRING(@phoneNumber, 7, 4)
END
```

Comment: también aplica para MySQL? por que ella lo plantea en su pregunta y tu especificas que funciona en SQL Server

Comment: Ahorita probaré si me funciona, si es así validaré la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

*Efectivamente me funcionó con tan solo el update de mi tabla*

```
update empleados
set N_Cel = substring(N_Cel,1,3) + '-' +
        substring(N_Cel,4,3) + '-'
```

Si a alguno le diera el error code 1175 para desactivar el update seguro solo debe:

```
SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

**Gracias :)**

Answer (score 0):

Tenía un problema similar, pero aumentado por la razón de que algunos teléfonos tenían el formato con los guiones y otros no lo tenían y este fue el comando que me ayudó a actualizar los formatos de los números que no tenían los guiones.

```
Teléfono antes del comando: 1234567890
Teléfono después del comando: 123-456-7890
El campo teléfono se llama phone_number y es un VARCHAR
```

El comando que usé es:

```
UPDATE base_de_datos.tabla 
SET phone_number = concat(SUBSTRING(phone_number,1,3) , '-' , SUBSTRING(phone_number,4,3) , '-' , SUBSTRING(phone_number,7,4)) 
WHERE LOCATE('-', phone_number) = 0;
```